# How do you solve a problem that is unreproducible, random and changes are not immediately testable?

Tags: testing, diagnostics

Thought I would throw this one out there and see what other people's experiences have been like.

I'm experiencing an issue with a system at work where it stops processing jobs in a queue and 'jams' so to speak. Once the services are restarted the software processes the queue and everything returns to normal.

In my experience so far, I cannot for the life of me figure out what is causing these stoppages. That, and I cannot reproduce the stoppage myself. The queue fails at all different intervals, sometimes running for a month straight, other times failing as close together as twice in 1 day. I have since involved two different vendors and various colleagues within the department and everyone is stumped, and has been for several months.

Since I started, we've isolated the processing to a single server and cranked up the logging which we've sent to the vendors.  Neither have no idea what the problem is.

We've updated a few settings here and there, upgraded client and server pieces, but we have no idea if the things we are doing is contributing to an overall solution.

So I have a problem that **appears to be unreproducible, random and untestable.**

Has anyone been involved with any similar situations? 
What are some of the ways to solve a situation like this?

Any shared input or experiences would be great.

Cheers,

**EDIT:**: Cranked up the logging, updated all of the components to the latest version, and made sure proper anti-virus exclusions were done and so far it has not jammed in over a month!

Comment: Could there be anything affecting the program's memory usage? I suppose you've done load testing and profiling? Other than that the only thing I can think of is that it jams on jobs with certain properties that may not be overly obvious... Are there any similarities in the jamming jobs that you can see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a logging framework that can be turned on in production.  You might have to have too much logging initially but it should help narrow down the problem and as you get closer you can narrow the scope of the logging and at the same time increase the verbosity (is that a word) of the remaining log statements.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the logging as pointed out by Kelly there is the possibilty of a deadlock taking place since things seem to stop. One option if this is a Java application is to use [jconsole](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) and connect to the JVM instance. jconsole has a detect deadlock option which can provide very valuable information when the hangup occurs.

If this is not a Java application and perhaps a .NET application you could make use of this [technique](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163618.aspx#S4).